# How to get list item Value in Sharepoint 2013 add-ins Workflow using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I want to get list item value in Workflow (add-ins) using REST API. I have used `httpsend` activity and in URI I have pasted the following:

```
http://.../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abcListName')/items$filter=ID eq '1'
```

I can see that the URL is picking up the result, and that the response in stored in Dynamic Value Type `tempDTT`, but `tempDTT` is empty. I am unable to see the output.

Comment: are you saying you want to read REST api output in WF? are you using "Call HTTP web service" action in Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get one item using his ID you can use the following URL:

```
http://.../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abcListName')/items(1)
```

This will result in only one item being returned. Your method will return a collection of items.

I find it hard to find the correct query to perform in SPD. It makes it easier to log the response dictionary as text to a multi line text field (for example in a custom list). Than you know the exact output and can define the correct query.